# Add / Import Sharepoint 2013 WebPart via REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I'm trying to figure out if I can import a web part via the REST API.

I've seen various CSOM examples of doing this, e.g.
[How to add a Web Part into a SitePages/Home.aspx using CSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268492/how-to-add-a-web-part-into-a-sitepages-home-aspx-using-csom)

I've exported a ListView web part, so I have an XML webpart definition file.

I can successfully call 
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/subsite/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/subsite/Pages/Info.aspx')/getlimitedwebpartmanager(scope=0)

The end point for importWebPart appears to exist, e.g.
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/subsite/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/subsite/Pages/Info.aspx')/getlimitedwebpartmanager(scope=0)/importWebPart

But I can't figure out what/how to post to it, the webpart definition is XML, but if I POST that then the API unsurprisingly says "Not well formatted JSON stream".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error most likely occurs since the `parameters` property is provided in invalid format, the below example demonstrates how to invoke `ImportWebPart` method:

> **Endpoint** `/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<pageurl>')/getlimitedwebpartmanager(1)/ImportWebPart`
>
> **Parameters** `{ webPartXml : <webpartxml> }`
>
> **HTTP method** `POST`
>
> Note: despite  `ImportWebPart` method is supported via REST API, it
>   seems `AddWebPart` method on the contrary is **not** supported at the
>   moment making the operation for adding web part on the page not applicable

---

**Example**

```
var webPartXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">' +
    '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>' + 
    '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
    '<Title>$Resources:core,ContentEditorWebPartTitle;</Title>' +
    '<Description>$Resources:core,ContentEditorWebPartDescription;</Description>' +
    '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>' +
'</WebPart>';
var zoneId = "TopColumnZone";
var zoneIndex = 0;
var pageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Pages/default.aspx"; 

importWebPart(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, pageUrl ,webPartXml,zoneId,zoneIndex)
.done(function(result)
{
    console.log('Web part has been imported successfully');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function importWebPart(webUrl, pageUrl,webPartXml,zoneId,zoneIndex){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + pageUrl + "')/getlimitedwebpartmanager(1)/ImportWebPart";
    var properties = {"webPartXml": webPartXml};
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "payload": properties})
}

function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("payload" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Vadim I can now call "importWebPart"
After that would come:

    var oWebPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.importWebPart(webPartXml);
    this.oWebPart = oWebPartDefinition.get_webPart();
    limitedWebPartManager.addWebPart(oWebPart, 'Left', 1);

But I'm not using the javascript interface, but doing REST calls from a separate application back-end.
I can't find the detail of what goes on inside the "addWebpart" function, so don't know if it's possible to build an equivalent REST API call.

I don't suppose this is also something you may know the answer to?
Thanks!

Comment: 'I can't find the detail of what goes on inside the "addWebpart" function': The AddWebPart_Client method of the SPLimitedWebPartManager class is the client-side equivalent of the AddWebPart method. Unfortunately, this method is decorated with a ClientCallableMethod attribute having ClientLibraryTargets=ClientLibraryTargets.NonRESTful, making this method unusable from REST calls.

Comment: @Vadim, do you possibly know why we get 200 as a response, but the web part does not appear on the page? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198009/cannot-import-a-web-part-using-rest-getlimitedwebpartmanager1-importwebpart

Comment: @Zerg00s, just wanted to confirm, it seems there is no way at the moment to actually import a web part since `AddWebPart` method is not callable via REST API  (see also valuable comment from @pholpar)

Comment: @VadimGremyachev. I see, thank you. I regret I've missed this comment